# Can't change the color od spinner divider

Tags: android, spinner, divider

My spinner is defined like this and it seems android:divider="#66BC31" has no effect, i still get white divider:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:divider="#66BC31"
    android:background="@drawable/spina" />
```

This is my code where i change my spinner font and select resource for dropdown:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Roaming.this,
            R.layout.roaming_spinner, data) {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt.ttf");
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

            return v;
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) { // we need this so we can use custom
                                    // font for spinner (open)
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

            Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt.ttf");
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);


            return v;
        }
    };
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.roaming_spinner_row);
```

I also tried adding line android:divider="#66BC31" to roaming_spinner_row.xml and roaming_spinner.xml where text size and color for my closed and opened spinner are declared and again with no success.

Comment: Try this implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491980/how-to-color-and-alignment-spinner-item-on-android

Answer (score 9):

I finally found the answer, thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918468/android-spinner-how-to-make-dropdown-view-transparent/7047187#7047187) and some more research.

What you have to do is define in your activity's theme

```
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/App.Style.Spinner</item>
```

and then create the proper style with

```
   <style name="App.Style.Spinner" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown">
           <item name="android:dividerHeight">10dip</item>
           <item name="android:divider">@drawable/mydivider</item>
   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Spinner's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) there is no reference to `android:divider`.

Comment: Any other way to change color of spinner divider or to remove it?

Comment: I have little experience on Android, so I don't know another way =(.