# Custom style setDropDownViewResource Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, xml

Below is my current code that adds my array_spinner to my adapter and then adds the adapter to my spinner. 
**QUESTIONS:**

1- I am not sure how I would use the following code to style my drop down:  `areaspinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` and how do I apply a custom view/text view? I need to style the text item in the spinner drop down.

2- Do I need to create a a separate layout.xml file for this view?

Any info would be great. Thanks!

```
array_spinner=new String[4];
array_spinner[0]="Select";
array_spinner[1]="George Washington";
array_spinner[2]="Benjamin Franklin";
array_spinner[3]="Thomas Jefferson";

 //CREATE SPINNER
areaspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.areaspinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_spinner);
areaspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. If your intention is to achieve different styling of drop down list items with respect to spinner view selected item styling, you have to indeed provide your custom layout id to `setDropDownViewResource()`. In your layout you just have to declare `TextView` as root element because it is required by `ArrayAdapter`
2. Yes, you need to create separate your_layout_name.xml file in res/layout directory for each layout you declare.

Comment: This was very helpful! I finally got it working by creating a new layout named spinner_layout.xml and then added adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you use the setDropDownViewResource() in your code

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
areaspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Sure it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use setDropDownViewResource(), you can simply provide your own theme, and override the style. See my answer here: [Android Spinner - How to make dropdown view transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918468/android-spinner-how-to-make-dropdown-view-transparent/7047187#7047187)

Answer (score 0):

Define a customer spinner_layout.xml with TextView as root view.
When setting the adapter layout, use the following code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_spinner, days);
```

OR

```
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_spinner);
```